# django-cms login_required doesn't work

Tags: django, django-cms

*Django*     == **1.5.4**

*Django-CMS* == **2.4.2**

Page flag "login_required" didn't work. It works only in main page, but in ALL inner pages it didn't. There is no any code modification in cms plugin.

"login_required" is checking in only one file : **/site-packages/cms/views.py** in line *136*:

```
# permission checks
if page.login_required and not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect_to_login(urlquote(request.get_full_path()), settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

I set

```
print "check"
```

above it and as was expected - it prints only in main page...

Any ideas what may be the problem ?

Comment: Works for me. Did you publish your changes to the child page(s)?

Comment: Found what it was... All problems in cms app_hook. There is only one function, which checks "login_required" flag - **detail** in "/site-packages/cms/views.py", which calls from "/site-packages/cms/urls.py"

But when we add an app_hook to page - django loads only app_hook urls.py and ignored cms urls.py... And as the result - function 'detail' won't be called and  checks will be ignored..

Shame... try to create a bag report...
Maybe somebody can advise something ???

Comment: I see. That does make sense, since control is handed from the CMS page to a page that is not under its control. Perhaps the CMS could pass an attribute to the app-hooked page to indicate that an ancestor page was login_required.

Comment: I try to make something like this.... see my answer below.
And create a bug report:

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/2480

Interesting, what developers of django-cms will answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of the problem was found in comments in question. I have solved it by writing custom *decorator* which checks *"login required"* flag of a cms-page:

**views.py (of app_hook)**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from project.decorators import check_login_required_flag

@check_login_required_flag
def index(request):
    """ private page index """    
    return render(request, 'private_room/index.html', {})
```

**decorators.py**:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from cms.utils.page_resolver import get_page_from_request

def check_login_required_flag(view_func):
    """
    Decorator checks 'login required' flag of a cms-page and redirect
    unauthorized user to login page
    """
    def _wrapped_view_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        page = get_page_from_request(request)
        if page and page.login_required:
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login')+'?next='+request.path)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view_func
```

Comment: Nice work. I would probably change the name to be more specific, like "check_cms_login_required"